# NSPredicate: how to use CONTAINS with NSDate field?

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I'd like to make my searchBar in swift to search in multiple fields of a (core data filled) tableview. The searchPredicate I use is:

```
Let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(itemDate contains[c] 
%@) OR (itemName contains[c] %@)", searchController.searchBar.text!,
searchController.searchBar.text!)
```

However itemDate is of type NSDate and this predicate fails: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection 2013-12-31 23:00:00 +0000 (not a collection)'

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(stringFromDate(itemDatum)
withFormat:@\"ccc d MMMM y\" contains[c] %@) OR (itemName contains[c] %@)", 
searchController.searchBar.text!, searchController.searchBar.text!)
```

returns 'Unable to parse function name 'stringFromDate:' into supported selector (stringFromDate:) ' So that was a stupid guess, ofcourse, but maybe it makes my question more understandable: I want people to start typing 'nov' or '2017' and immediately get proper results, like as with strings.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: I'd suggest to use `predicateWithBlock:`

Comment: Thanks. I believe that's not a Swift-function but it defenitely gives me some new directions to google my way out of this :)

Comment: It's a Cocoa Touch method that exists in Swift.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't find out how to use that one but I found a workaround!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 var searchPredicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate { (AnyObject indx, NSDictionary bindings) -> Bool in

        var itemN: String? = indx.valueForKey("itemName") as? String
        var itemD: String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(indx.valueForKey("itemDatum") as! NSDate)

        var searchBarText: String = searchController.searchBar.text.lowercaseString

        return itemN?.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchBarText) != nil || itemD.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchBarText) != nil
    }
```